# Error While Connecting to Oracle 18c by Toad 12.9

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, toad

if I connect using oraDB18Home1 then following error apear.

> Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-12541
>
> Items Checked
>
> TNS_ADMIN environment variable is defined as
>   "C:\app\muhiuddin\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin"
>
> "C:\app\muhiuddin\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin\sqlnet.ora"
>   was located
>
> NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH specifies EZCONNECT in the sqlnet.ora file
>
> Steps to Take Verify that the correct port is specified Verify that
>   the listener is running and that it is properly configured Try to ping
>   LOCALHOST using the Ping button on the toolbar Try to TNSPing
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=LOCALHOST)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=>
>
> > (SERVICE_NAME=XE))) using the TNS Ping button on the toolbar

if i connect through client it shows following message

> ORA-12541: TNS:no listener
>
> Items Checked
>
> TNS_ADMIN environment variable is defined as
>   "C:\app\muhiuddin\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin"
>
> "C:\app\muhiuddin\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\network\admin\sqlnet.ora"
>   was located
>
> NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH specifies EZCONNECT in the sqlnet.ora file
>
> Steps to Take Verify that the correct port is specified Verify that
>   the listener is running and that it is properly configured Try to ping
>   LOCALHOST using the Ping button on the toolbar Try to TNSPing
>   (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=LOCALHOST)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=>
>   (SERVICE_NAME=XE))) using the TNS Ping button on the toolbar.

My tnsnames.ora has

> XE = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =
>   DESKTOP-622AB3J)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)
>   (SERVICE_NAME = XE) ) )

and listner.ora has

> ## listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\muhiuddin\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
>
> Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
>
> DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE
>
> SID_LIST_LISTENER = (SID_LIST = (SID_DESC = (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
>   (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\muhiuddin\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE) (PROGRAM =
>   extproc) (ENVS =
>   "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\muhiuddin\product\18.0.0\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr18.dll") ) )
>
> LISTENER = (DESCRIPTION_LIST = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL =
>   TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-622AB3J)(PORT = 1521)) (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL =
>   IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521)) ) )

[image]

I can connect through sqlplus as sys. but when i ping "tnsping xe" it give me message no listenere in command line

Comment: You have more than one Oracle Client installed on your machine, most likely there you have a conflict or mess up. Remove the Oracle 19 client, I don't know any reason to have more than one client (per architecture, i.e. 32-bit vs. 64-bit) installed. The Oracle database always include all client libraries.

Comment: That means your listener is down.Check services if listener is up and running or run the command from elevated dos prompt (if on windows) `lsnrrctl status` if down start the service `lsnrctl start`

Comment: In your slqnet.ora file set `NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)` - EZCONNECT does not use the `tnsnames.ora` file where you defined the alias.

Answer (score 0):

First step run :

```
 lsnrctl status
```

then activate the following service
[image]